# How do I match accent characters in ANSI text file?

Tags: gold-parser

I'm trying to match accent character in ANSI file, and they are recognized as EOF.

The text file is:
VALB. VIÑAS - CICLÓN

The grammar I'm using is:
`"Start Symbol" = <Value>
    {String Ch} = {All Printable} + {Control Codes} + {All Valid}
    String     = {String Ch}+
    <Value>   ::= String`

and it matches the Ñ char as EOF and terminate.

Is there a way to tell gold parser that the file is ANSI?